# Display image from wwwroot

Tags: c#

I want to show my image which is in `wwwroot/Uploads` if I put localhost/wwwroot/imageName.extension file is not showing but if I remove wwwroot and pass only localhost/Uploads/imageName.extension then file is able to display. But I need it as the first one please help me I shall be very thankful to you.

I want this image to display by providing the above url but in this it is unable to show:

- https://localhost:44362/wwwroot/Uploads/img23.png

In this case - this url:

- https://localhost:44362/Uploads/img23.png

it is able to display, but i don't need this. I need it like the above i wrote.
https://localhost:44362/wwwroot/Uploads/img23.png (My requirement).

Comment: did you try to create a wwwroot folder inside your wwwroot and move your assets there?

Answer (score 2):

The wwwroot folder is a feature that comes in with ASP.NET 5.0.

All of the static files in your project should goes into this folder. These are assets that the app will serve **directly** to clients, including html, css, javascript and image files. The wwwroot folder is the **root** of your web site.

So `http://localhost:port/` **points to wwwroot** -  all URLs for static content are relative to the wwwroot folder (you can use paths that reflects directory structure of your wwwroot).

So then - if you want to have this `/wwwroot/` element in your URL you need to create **another** folder called `wwwroot` inside your wwwroot directory (what a loop)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir stay blessed

Comment: Wow its working now but sir now i want this clickable when i click on the file it needs to be open by hitting the same directory it has been saved

Answer (score 0):

I you *really* want it that way, create a wwwroot folder inside your wwwroot folder and move the files there.
This should be your final structure

```
wwwroot
->wwwroot
-->Uploads
--->img32.png
```